# Can't reach web server from local virtual network

Tags: linux, webserver, iptables

I have installed a couple of virtual machines. Some uder Windows, some under Fedora Linux. On one of the Fedora machined I've installed Apache web server.

I have setup server name in httpd.conf to `172.16.27.129:80`, made sure the access to html directory is `Allow from all`, and populated that directory with test `.html` file. After starting httpd, I've got web server working locally.

Then I tried to access it from other machine and failed. Just getting 'Firefox can't establish a connection' message.

Error logs on server machine are empty. I thought it could be the firewall, so I made my iptables setup like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
```

Still no luck. I thought it could be something with the network. But I have a Subversion server working via HTTPS on one of my virtual Windows machines, so network should be fine.

At this point I've run out of ideas. What did I miss?

UPDATE: It has to be iptables. I just tuned it off and the whole thing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

The problem here is that both of the lines that have to do with HTTP and HTTPS traffic come immediately after the `REJECT` entry, which means that those rules aren't being seen at all. They need to be put into the IPTABLES configuration before the `REJECT`, otherwise they are going to be blocked.